# Найти количество тегов на странице

Tags: count, функции, preg_match, php

Есть функция, которая должна вытащить все теги strong на странице:

```
function parsstrong($website) {
    if(mb_detect_encoding($website) != "ASCII"){ //если URL в кириллице переводим в punycode
        include_once("idna_convert.class.php");
        $IDN = new idna_convert(array('idn_version' => '2008'));
        $website=$IDN->encode($website);
        }
    $rz = getpage($website);
    if (preg_match_all('|<strong.*?>(.*)</strong>|sei',$rz, $matched)){
        $result = $matched[1];
        return $result;
        }
    else return 'NULL';
}
```

Когда пытаюсь вызвать, у меня показывает всегда 1 совпадение:

```
echo count(parsstrong($website)); // 1
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так? Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 1):

[@theblackpost](/users/25668/theblackpost)

```
if (..) { .. return .. } else return 'NULL';
```

лучше писать вот так

```
if (..) { .. return .. } return null;
```

а вообще если функция не возвращает результата, то он и так будет null:

```
if (..) { .. return .. } // с точки зрения внешнего интерфейса ничего не поменялось
```

Comment: Проблема-то в том, что как раз выводит не NULL, выводит всегда 1, даже если на странице больше 1 тега.

Comment: @Etki, пробовал добавлять count наоборот в `return count($repcharset);` - результат тот же.

А `var_dump(parsstrong($narray)`, если `$count = count($repcharset);`
говорит `int(1)`.

При `$count = $repcharset;` возвращается:
 
    array(1) { [0]=> string(200) "стронгстронгстронгстронгстронгстронгстронг 7" }

Comment: Вообщем, решил вопрос так:
     $list = explode("\r\n", $result);

=)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут надо смотреть в сторону модификатора U (Ungreedy), он должен выдавать все вхождения.